# initializing an object in an array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I've been playing around with arrays for some time and this problem has been troubling me.

I created a user defined object and declared it in an array like this: `Property regesteredAssets[] = new Property[200];

And here's my constructor: `

```
public Property(String newPropertyName,String newPropertyAddress,String newPropertyType, String newPropertyDescription)
    {

    propertyName[arraySequence] = newPropertyName;
    propertyFullAddress[arraySequence] = newPropertyAddress;
    propertyType[arraySequence] = newPropertyType;
    propertyDescription[arraySequence] = newPropertyDescription;

        arraySequence++;



}
```

I want to initialize each array `regesteredAsssets[]` according to my desire. How can I do it?
Do I have to use arrays in my attributes in the `Property` class too?

Comment: It's just semantics but I prefer to declare arrays off their type. `Property[] registeredAssets;` as opposed to `Property registeredAssets[];`. Easier to spot the arrays and single objects down the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need your attributes to be arrays, unless a particular asset has multiple of something. In this case, I don't think it does. You can greatly simplify your code as follows:

```
public class Property {
    private String name, address, type, description;

    public Property(String name, String address, String type, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.type = type;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Property[] registeredAssets = new Property[200];

        registeredAssets[0] = new Property("Joe Bloggs", "555 Fake St.", "IMPORTANT", "Lorem Ipsum Dolor");
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of type Property, you can set each of the elements up using the following code:

```
regesteredAssets[0] = new Property( enterYourParametersHere );
```

I assume the fields in your Property constructor are single fields, and therefore you do not need to set them using the array notation `field[index] = value`, and indeed, if the Property class is of the consistency I think it is, then this will produce a compilation error.

If you wanted to set up multiple entries in your array, you could perform the initialisation step inside a loop, providing a loop index to the index of the array as below:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    regesteredAssets[i] = new Property( enterYourParametersHere );
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks! so, everytime I pass a new argument to a new regesteredAsset[i]; do those arguments get assigned to that particular object?

Comment: Yes, the arguments should be provided through the constructor and each time `regesteredAsset[i]` is hit, the Property instance at index `i` in the array will have those arguments, as per the constructor code.